# Metafizzy isotope - entering animation

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-isotope

All the information I can find about animating in isotope is for version 1: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for isotope 2.
Does anyone know how I could change the appended entering animation? At the moment it's a scale transition from 0 to the appropriate size: see example here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the`visibleStyle`, `hiddenStyle` and `transitionDuration` options:

For example, to slowly fade in/out without scale:

```
var isotope = new Isotope(someElement, {
  hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 },
  visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 },
  transitionDuration: '2s'
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/2qgmb2Le/)

Source: [Isotope Options documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#hiddenstyle).

Comment: In the above code transitionDuration: 2s should be transitionDuration: '2s'